# In a Multilayer CNN, which inputs takes the 2nd layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm uncertain about the following question, all I've found on the internet seemed vague and fuzzy.

Consider this CNN:

```
model = Sequential()
# 1st conv layer
model.add(Conv2D(10, (4,4), actiavtion="relu", input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
# 2nd conv layer
model.add(Conv2D(20, (4,4), actiavtion="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Now, when the input image is passed to the first conv layer, we result in 10 features maps, each of them of the shape `(25, 25, 1)`. Hence, we result in the shape of `(25, 25, 1, 10)`, correct? Applying the Pooling leads us to `(12, 12, 1, 10)`.

My question appears when it comes to the second conv layer. A conv layer always takes one picture/matrix as input. Like the first layer took `(28, 28, 1)`, which is **one** picture.

But conv layer 1 gave us 10 pictures (or feature maps). So, which of these 10 is used as the input? I'd assume every single one.

Suppose that is correct: So, we have the input shape `(12, 12, 1)` for the second conv layer. Applying it results in `(9, 9, 1)` and the Pooling layer gives then `(4, 4, 1)`. Since we have 20 features specified, we result in `(4, 4, 1, 20)`.

But that's only for **one** of the 10 possible inputs! Therefore, if we apply all of them, we'd have the final shape `(4, 4, 1, 20, 10)`. Correct?

**Edit:**

The weight calculation makes me think it's correct because it fits.
On the other hand, the flatten layer only has `320 = 4*4*20` neurons, not `3200 = 4*4*20*10` like I would expect it. So that would make me think it's not correct.

This is the output of the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 25, 25, 10)        170       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 12, 12, 10)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 9, 9, 20)          3220      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 20)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 320)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 128)               41088     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 45,768
Trainable params: 45,768
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

And if the initial input shape would have been an RGB picture (e.g. `(28, 28, 3)`), we would result in `(4, 4, 3, 20, 10)`?

Comment: I believe there is a connection from every one of input 10 channels to the output 20 channels, just like a neural network with input layer of size `N` and output layer of size `M` has a connection between every neuron (`N x M` matrix multiplication). Such a multiplication outputs `M` (as expected), not `N x M`.

Comment: That leads me to think that when you specify the filter to be `4 x 4`, it's size is actually `4 x 4 x <# of input channels`.

Comment: Use model.summary() to see what are the output shapes of the layers

Comment: @Lowry, I've printed the model.summary() in the post. Apparently my assumption is false.

Comment: @Mario Ishac, and how exactly? I don't really understand.

Comment: @LukasNießen The filters here are 3D, not 2D. Specifically, when going from 10 input channels to 20 output channels in your example, there are 20 4 by 4 by 10 filters. This image might clear it up: https://miro.medium.com/max/1800/1*ySaRmKSilLahyK2WxXC1bA.png

Comment: @MarioIshac I don't understand how a 3D filter works then. I'm very confused.

Comment: I think the clue is that Conv2D receives a 3D input instead of a 2D. And I don't know how Conv2D computes a 2D output out of it. So I've found [this](https://qr.ae/pNyr4R). According to that answer, if I got it correct, it works this way: Out of 10 input channels (just like 3 RGB channels), it computes each time 20 new feature maps. So we'd first have 200 maps. But then, they are added on each other in this way: Assume `M[1-10][1-20]` would be the 200 maps. Then we finally result in the following 20 feature maps: `(M[1][1]+...+M[10][1], ..., M[1][20]+...+M[10][20])`. Is that the way it works?

Comment: @LukasNießen Yes, I think you can also think of it like that. A filter applied against a given input channel would generate a matrix of subsignals. All these matrices of subsignals (one for each input channel) are consolidated element-wise to generate the final matrix of signals for that filter, accounting for all input channels. My answer explains this consolidation step at a different point in the process, see if that makes sense as well (specifically, this consolidation is baked into the element-wise multiplication instead of being done explicitly at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that even though you provide 2 numbers to the filter (4 for width and 4 for height in your example), the filter is actually 3D. This 3rd dimension represents the number of input channels.

Let's go through the first convolution layer: `Conv2D(10, (4,4), actiavtion="relu", input_shape=(28,28,1)`.

We have an input shape of `(28, 28, 1)`, and filter shape of `(4, 4, 1)`. Even though you specified the shape to be `(4, 4)` in that line above, remember that the third dimension will be the number of input channels, which for this first convolution layer, is 1. If you were feeding RGB images into your model, for example, both the input shape **and** filter would have the third dimension be 3 instead of 1.

Our output shape, given our input shape and filter shape, should be `(input_shape[0] - filter_shape[0] + 1, input_shape[1] - filter_shape[1] + 1, output_channels)` (assuming the stride is 1, which it is in your model). Substituting values, we get `(28 - 4 + 1, 28 - 4 + 1, 10)`, or `(25, 25, 10)`. This confirms what we see in `model.summary()`.

As for how we go from input to output under the hood, first we need to move the filter across the input, both horizontally and vertically. An input of shape `(28, 28, 1)`, with a filter of shape `(4, 4, 1)`, would yield a chunked input of shape `(25, 25, 4, 4, 1)`. In other words, we have have `25 x 25` "views" of our original image, with each of these views having shape `(4, 4, 1)` representing the pixel values we see in the image.

We have 10 `(4, 4, 1)` filters (10 being number of output channels). Let's take the first of these filters. Let's also take the first "view" of our original image (remember, we have `25 x 25` in total). We multiply the filter by this "view" [element-wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), which works out great because both the filter and the "view" are of the same shape `(4, 4, 1)`. The nature of this multiplication gives us an output "view" of shape `(4, 4, 1)`. We then add all these values (`4 x 4 x 1 = 16` values total) to give our "signal". Larger sum of these values would mean stronger detection of whatever the filter is looking for. I've overlooked some things, like bias, but that doesn't change the dimensionality of things.

The above walk through only dealt with the first filter and first "view" of our image, and resulted in a single scalar "signal". We have 10 filters, and `25 x 25` views, yielding a final output shape of `(25, 25, 10)` (as expected).

Note how the entire process operated in 3D space. Both the filters and views were 3D, in this case with a last dimension of 1. It is able to operate in 3D space because the element-wise multiplication will work out, as long as both the filter and "view" have the same 3rd dimension (1 in this case).

If we went through the second convolution layer (`Conv2D(20, (4,4), actiavtion="relu")`), that last dimension of both the filter and "view" would be 10 instead of 1. This is because the output channels of the previous convolution layer are the same as the input channels of the current one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But honestly, although I've learned much from that answer, I don't see where it actually answers the initial question. Mostly, you're talking about the first layer, and about the second one you just say that it still works because the shapes fit. However, that answer **in combination** with my last comment and your response, absolutely answers the question, so I'll mark this with the green check anyway. Thank you!